# How to get Email MetaData (ConversationId, Category) in Chrome Extension for Outlook

Tags: google-chrome-extension, outlook, office-js

**Background:**

I am building a chrome extension for outlook OWA (office and live.com).
The extension provides some feedback about an email to our Backend.
For the same I need the email Metadata like ItemId, Conversation Id.
How do I get the above metadata ? For Gmail we had good support from InboxSDK to give us the needed ThreadId. But I am clueless how to do this for OWA.

**What I tried**

*I have already tried the following :*

1. E.g this : https://outlook.office.com/owa/service.svc?action=FindConversation&EP=1&UA=0&ID=-4 Call seems to give data. 
   Tried making service.svc calls but I have not been able to figure out how to exactly call them, as the API call fails with auth errors.
2. I was really hoping the office.js would help here as I have an addin that gets me the needed info via an API call. However, even though I managed to load the office.js its missing the 'context'. and the office.OnReady does not trigger.

**Question**

What is the way to get the current email's metadata programatically in a chrome extension by making use of the fact that OWA is already a outlook client.

Can I find this Data somewhere in DOM or may be make a API call to some MS API with the cookie info already available to the extension ?

Comment: Found a way to get at least get the conversation Id : 
The middle pane shows the list of threads :

<div data-convid="ABCDADAwATMwMAItMTk1YS04NjYAMi0wMAItMDAKABAAuNSQDX7LSaqICvixxNV510A==" tabindex="0" >

Comment: Office.js will only function correctly if you load it inside an Outlook Web Addin. With a corresponding manifest and hosted files. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins?context=outlook/context) Office.js won't work if you just load it into a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few design considerations and perhaps some APIs / functionalities misunderstood but still - what you want to do is achievable.

Let's start with what you've tried.
*Office.js* is an extension API. It's a special JavaScript library which allows you to communicate with the Office clients, through a special context that those clients are creating. You basically include this into a webpage and point your client to that webpage so they can communicate. You would have to side-load / or install the Office add-in from the store. Both of these options require an add-in manifest, where you define the endpoint that the client is going to call. **So it's not a random JS library which will function without Office context. For the Office context to be present, you have to be in the Office client / or Office web and using an Office add-in, which has Office.js**. Just being on those pages is not sufficient.

For your #1 - auth problems - you'd get auth related issues because you aren't authenticated against that API. You'd have to register an application, get an OAuth token and call some API like Graph to get additional details that you're looking for.

Now - I understand that you want to develop something only for web and you want to use a Chrome Extension (potentially an already existing one for GMail). I'll suggest a few options, with one of them not including this. I can think of a few ways to do this.

#### 1 - Don't use a chrome extension.

Office add-ins are meant to be cross platform, which means they'll work with Office web as well as Office clients. You'd be able to get the data you want fairly easily using this. Consider implementing your solution using Office.js framework. This would however require the add-in to be activated for you to collect data (it can't run in the background) and kept as activated. If your Chrome Extension is passively collecting data (thought privacy much?) / or passively providing feedback this might not the best way to go.

#### 2 - Register an app to call Microsoft Graph.

If you know which email you want to process (based on sender / subject / etc...) you can register an app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. If you request to access user's mailbox and user grants it, you'd be able to access user's emails offline. With that you can process what you need to and when you think it's ok (either through detecting the domain, or the user opening chrome) you can notify them through your Chrome Extension. This could be done in a few ways but the simplest one would be sockets I'd imagine.

#### 3 - For only the current mail item

All of the UI queries might fail tomorrow, because what you're trying to do is undocumented. However the URL, when you're viewing a particular item includes an ID.
You can try registering an app same as step #2 (add the mail access scopes) and query graph for that Id to get it in the runtime. You should be able to fire off that query from your chrome extension. So it would be like

1. Create app
2. When user is using chrome extension + outlook - prompt for authentication
3. Once the user authenticates, save refresh token + access token.
4. Get the item id from the URL.
5. Call Microsoft Graph with the item id, using the access token to authenticate.
6. Item details should be returned in a json.

When the user re-visits the outlook domain, you can renew the access token by using the refresh token.